# Unable to track SelectedItem of DataGrid inside RowDetailsTemplate of another Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, rowdetailstemplate

I ran into this problem earlier today and am unable to find a solution. The `SelectedItem` of a `DataGrid` that's inside the `RowDetailsTemplate` of another `DataGrid` is not being set when I select a row inside the `DataGrid` that's inside the `RowDetailsTemplate`. (Difficult to explain clearly.)

The bindings are all working properly for the lists. The MainViewModel contains an `ObservableCollection` of `MyItem` objects and that's what the outer `DataGrid` binds to.

The `MyItem` object contains an `ObservableCollection` of `MyItem2` objects and they get bound correctly to the inner `DataGrid`.

The `MyItem` object also has a property called `SelectedItem2` which is supposed to be bound to the `SelectedItem` of the inner `DataGrid` but never gets set.

BTW: I'm using VS2012 and .Net 4.5.

Example:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainVm"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainVm}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItem1s}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>         
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Item2s}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem2}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item 2 Name" Width="130"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

`MainWindowViewModel`

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var item1 = new MyItem1();
            item1.Name = i.ToString();
            for (int j = 11; j < 20; j++)
                item1.Item2s.Add(new MyItem2()
                    {
                        Name = j.ToString()
                    });
            MyItem1s.Add(item1);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyItem1> _myItem1S = new ObservableCollection<MyItem1>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem1> MyItem1s
    {
        get { return _myItem1S; }
        set { _myItem1S = value; }
    }
}
```

`MyItems ViewModels`

```
 public class MyItem1 : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;        
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyItem2> _item2S = new ObservableCollection<MyItem2>();        
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem2> Item2s
    {
        get { return _item2S; }
        set
        {
            _item2S = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Item2s");
        }
    }

    private MyItem2 _selectedItem2;
    public MyItem2 SelectedItem2
    {
        get { return _selectedItem2; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem2");
        }
    }
}

public class MyItem2 : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

}
```

`ViewModelBase`

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what do u want to do here exactly ? would you like to display the selecteditem of the first Datagrid in the RowDetails of the second Datagrid ? the question is not clear to understand. pls edit your question

Answer (score 3):

Ahh that's simple you aren't taking advantage of your onpropertychanged

try this on your datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:MyItem1}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Item2s}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem2,   
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

......
......
......

you need the updatesourcetrigger, i just put up code for your one binding but it needs to be done wherever you plan on updating the value using propertychanged

I usually use dependency properties so you don't need to do this, but doing a little research on dependency properties and notifypropertychanged you can find the one you want.